# Extending C Brute Force Algorithm

Tags: c, brute-force

I need a brute force algorithm over alphanumeric characters.

The code I use just prints all the permutations to the standard output. I tried for hours but failed to rewrite the code in such a manner that I can just call a function `brute_next()` to get the next codeword when needed.

Can someone help me rewrite this code? The function `brute_next()` should return a `char*` or alternatively gets an `char*` as parameter. I'm using CLion with gcc under Mac.

The code is ([source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/brute-force-algorithm-in-c)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const char alphabet[] =
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"0123456789";

static const int alphabetSize = sizeof(alphabet) - 1;

void bruteImpl(char* str, int index, int maxDepth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; ++i)
    {
        str[index] = alphabet[i];

        if (index == maxDepth - 1) printf("%s\n", str);
        else bruteImpl(str, index + 1, maxDepth);
    }
}

void bruteSequential(int maxLen)
{
    char* buf = malloc(maxLen + 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLen; ++i)
    {
        memset(buf, 0, maxLen + 1);
        bruteImpl(buf, 0, i);
    }

    free(buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    bruteSequential(3);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my non-working attempt to convert the recursion into a generator. Just can't figure out how the permutation algorithm works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char alphabet[] =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "0123456789"
        "$%&/()=.-_;!+*#";

static const int alphabetSize = sizeof(alphabet) - 1;

struct bruteconfig {
    int index;
    int i1;
    int i2;
    char* str;
    int maxDepth;
};

static struct bruteconfig* config;

void brute_init(int maxLen){
    free(config);
    config = malloc(sizeof(struct bruteconfig*));

    config->i1 = 1;
    config->i2 = 0;
    config->index = 0;
    config->maxDepth = maxLen;
}

void bruteImpl()
{
    if(config->i2 > alphabetSize)   // how to transform for to iterative?
        config->i2 = 0;

    config->str[config->index] = alphabet[config->i2];

    if (config->index == config->maxDepth - 1) {
        //printf("%s\n", config->str);
        return; // str filled with next perm
    }
    else {
        config->index++;
        //bruteImpl(config->str, config->maxDepth);
    }

    config->i2++;
}

char* bruteSequential()
{
    config->str = malloc(config->maxDepth + 1);

    if(config->i1 >= config->maxDepth)
        return NULL;

    memset(config->str, 0, config->maxDepth + 1); // clear buf
    bruteImpl(config->str, config->i1);       // fill with next perm

    return config->str;
    //free(buf);    // needs to be done by the caller
}
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question itself, not as external links. Trim down anything not necessary to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: 1: convert the recursive function to iterative function. Note that your function just increments index by one each call, so it could be `for (int index = 0; index != maxDepth - 1; index++)`. 2: identify "context" - ie. all variables that are needed to identify in what position in the code you are. That would be all local variables in your functions. 3: Create a `struct brute_ctx_s { /* members */ }` structure that will hold all the context variables for you function and pass the context via a pointer to your functions. Let all local variables use the context.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks! That's exactly what my attempt was. However, i just can't figure out how the algorithm works. I tried to convert it to an iterative algorithm saving the local variables in a struct but the output's just plain wrong...

Comment: 4: Note, that if you return a `char*` variable, you have to manage it's memory. Decide if you know the maximum length of such variable and want to use static allocation or dynamic. 5. So the function may look like `char *brute_next(struct brute_ctx_s *ctx)` and you most probably also need `int brute_start(struct brute_ctx_s *ctx)` and `bool brute_end(struct brute_ctx_s *ctx)` to start and stop the brute sequence you generate. Subjectively, I would go with pointers, ex. `int brute_next(struct brute_ctx_s *ctx, char **ret, size_t *size)`, but that's me. 6. `size_t` type is for representing size.

Comment: @KamilCuk I will try it once again an post my attempt..

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried it again but, yes with very dirty code but just to get it working but I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just can't figure out how the permutation algorithm works

It's quite simple: To get from one word to the next, start at the rightmost position, change that character to the next in the alphabet; if there's no next character, reset the position to the first character in the alphabet and continue with changing the position to the left; if there's no position left, the codeword needs to be lengthened. Here's a sample implementation:

```
char *brute_next()
{
    for (; ; )
    {
        static char *buf;               // buffer for codeword
        static int maxDepth;            // length of codeword
        int i, index = maxDepth-1;      // alphabet and buffer index, resp.
        while (0 <= index)              // as long as current length suffices:
        {   // next char at buf[index] is next in alphabet or first:
            i = buf[index] ? strchr(alphabet, buf[index]) - alphabet + 1 : 0;
            if (buf[index] = alphabet[i]) return buf;

            buf[index--] = alphabet[0]; // reset to 'a', continue to the left
        }
        index = maxDepth++;             // now need to lengthen the codeword
        buf = realloc(buf, maxDepth+1); // string length + terminator
        if (!buf) exit(1);
        buf[index] = buf[maxDepth] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works like charm. Oh! Then I was right, I looked at the output over the alphabet "abc" and came to this conclusion but it was way too confusing to rewrite the code to archive this. I need to free the returned pointer only when I'm finished calling a brute_next() x times right? Or after every call?
Still working out how the the while loop works.

Comment: You're right, you _need to free the returned pointer only_ once. But note that there's a limitation of this sample code: There's no provision to restart a sequence of `brute_next()` calls from the beginning. To do that, one could add a parameter to the function that causes `buf` and `maxDepth` to be cleared. - Concerning the rewriting of the original code: That would be quite easy in languages like Python which have _generator functions_; in C, a straightforward way could be using (non-portable) coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to switch from recursion to using a generator: the key difference is that recursion stores working state implicitly in the call stack, while a generator needs to store all its state explicitly for the next call.

So, first you need to think about what state is being implicitly held for you in the recursive version:

- each level of your recursive call has its own value for the parameter `index`
- each level has its own value for the local variable `i`
- ... and that's it.

You have `maxDepth` levels, numbered `0..maxDepth-1`, each with its own current position in the alphabet. Note that the `index` argument is also just the position in this collection, so you don't need to store it separately.

Now, you need to store some persistent state between calls, and it's going to be this array of `maxDepth` integer alphabet positions. Can you figure out how to write a function to convert that array into a string? Can you figure out how to advance the state one place in the same way your recursive code would?

---

**Edit** your state should probably look something like

```
struct PermutationState {
  /* stringLength == maxDepth */
  int stringLength;
  char *string;
  /* better to avoid globals */
  int alphaLength;
  const char *alphabet;
  /* this replaces i as the index into our alphabet */
  int *alphaPos;
};
```

and I'd suggest writing an interface like

```
struct PermutationState* start_permutation(int stringLength,
                                           int alphaLength,
                                           const char *alphabet)
{
  struct PermutationState *state = malloc(sizeof(*state));
  if (!state) return NULL;
  /* initialize scalar values first, for easier error-handling */
  state->stringLength = stringLength;
  state->string = NULL;
  state->alphaLength = alphaLength;
  state->alphabet = alphabet;
  state->alphaPos = NULL;

  /* now we can handle nested allocations */
  state->string = malloc(stringLength + 1);
  state->alphaPos = calloc(stringLength, sizeof(int));
  if (state->string && state->alphaPos) {
    /* both allocations succeeded, and alphaPos is already zeroed */
    memset(state->string, alphabet[0], stringLength);
    state->string[stringLength] = 0;
    return state;
  }

  /* one or both of the nested allocations failed */
  end_permutation(state);
  return NULL;
}

void end_permutation(struct PermutationState *state)
{
    free(state->string);
    free(state->alphaPos);
    free(state);
}
```

and finally you're looking to implement this function:

```
char *next_permutation(struct PermutationState *state)
{
    /* TODO */
}
```

Since `start_permutation` has already set you up with `state->alphaPos = [0, 0, ... 0]` and `state->string = "aaa...a"`, you probably want to advance `alphaPos` by one position and then return the current string.

NB. I assumed you don't need to copy the alphabet, which means the caller is responsible for guaranteeing its lifetime. You could easily copy that too, if necessary.

Comment: Rewriting to an iterative algorithm and saving the local variables was also my idea but it gave me the wrong output, I just can't figure out how the permutation algorithm works, but I will try again and post my attempt... thanks

Comment: I tried another attempt und updated my post but I don't know how to do it, it don't works.

Comment: You have a single value of `index`, and two (for some reason) value of `i`. I said you needed `maxDepth` copies of `i`, which means you need an array, not a fixed number of named variables!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!! I will try to implement the structure you gave me, another user just posted a very small working code but it's good for learning I think...